# VS 2017 enable warning about missing XML comments

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xamarin, compiler-warnings

So there's a lot of questions and how-tos on the internet about disabling the XML comment warnings in Visual Studio.

However, I'm not getting them and actually want to enable that feature. I'm using VS 2017 Enterprise and developing a Xamarin.Forms app for iOS and Android if that's relevant.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you actually generating the XML comment file? If you are, and you haven't disabled CS1591, it should generate warnings for any public types...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get the warnings, you have to ask for the XML documentation file to be built.

This is normally found in the Project Properties, in the `Build` tab under `Output` - there should be a checkbox for the XML documentation file. (And note that it's a per-build-configuration setting)

I couldn't guarantee that it's available for the specific project type you're asking for.